# How to delete item from the BindingList , binded with gridview?

Tags: c#, list, data-binding, bindinglist

I have a gridview where i am using a binding list for binding. In this grid i can add/remove item n times. So i want expression that if i delete a row from grid, it will delete the same item from the list. My List is BindingList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way better approach. The code removes the selected row from dataGrid and from bindingList:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BindingList<Person> bList;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bList = new BindingList<Person> 
            {
                new Person{ id=1,name="John"},
                new Person{id=2,name="Sara"},
               new Person{id=3,name="Goerge"}
            };
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bList;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string item = dataGridView1[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            if (item != null && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex != 0)
            {
                int _id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value);
                var bList_Temp = bList.Where(w => w.id == _id).ToList();

                //REMOVE WHOLE ROW:
                foreach (Person p in bList_Temp)
                    bList.Remove(p);
            }
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Mitja

Answer (score 0):

If your dataGrid is bound to a dataSource, like BindingList, you have to delete the item in the dataSource (in BinidngList).
Check this out:

BindingList bList;

```
private void buttonRemoveSelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string item = dataGridView1[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    if (item != null)
    {
        int _id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value);
        foreach (Person p in bList)
        {
            if (p.id == _id)
                p.name = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Mitja