# How to remove a row from a DataGridView using a BindingList as a DataSource?

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, delete-row, bindinglist

I have a datagridview, Source is BindingList, which contains name, date and pos. I'm using this to add new users to it:

```cs
public void Add(employee add) { mylist.Add(add); }
employees workers = new employees();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    workers.Add(new employee(textBox1.Text, dateTimePicker1.Value, textBox2.Text));
    var data = workers.MyList.Select(bring => new
    {
        Name = bring._Name,
        Date = bring._Date,
        Position = bring._Position,
    }).ToList();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
}
```

And I have a button to delete, but it throws an exception that System.InvalidOperationException or smth like that. Here is what I tried to use:

```cs
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    if (!row.IsNewRow)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
}
```

also this: `workers.MyList.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a selected DataGridViewRow and update a connected database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084346/how-to-delete-a-selected-datagridviewrow-and-update-a-connected-database-table)

Comment: @YongShun nope, nothing from it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete item from the BindingList , binded with gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409100/how-to-delete-item-from-the-bindinglist-binded-with-gridview)

Comment: BindingList does not allow one-to-one updates. Only the DataTable or Typed DataSet design, for example, supports this. You can use a [BindingListView](https://github.com/waynebloss/BindingListView) (implement INotifyPropertyChanged if needed, otherwise this class offers all that is needed plus sorting and filtering), thus when a row is deleted in the bindinglistview, it will be reflected in the grid (must also be deleted in the database if the data comes from it), but deleting a row do teh same: `myGrid.Rows.RemoveAt(index);` and it is deleted in the bindinglistview and so the source list.